# Enterprise Architect Code Generation: Get tags of interface

Tags: code-generation, enterprise-architect

I use Enterprise Architect for code generation and I would like to automatically retrieve all tags (in my case Java annotations) of the interfaces that a class realizes. Consider the following example:

[image]

From this model, I want to generate a class that looks like this:

```
@AnnotationOfMyInterface
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

So I want to add annotations as tags to `MyInterface` that should be applied to `MyClass` during code generation. In the UI, tags of implemented interfaces are shown so I was hoping there is a way to get these tags during code generation.

I tried to edit the code generation templates and found macros to get

1. All interfaces that a class implements: `%list="ClassInterface" @separator=", "%`
2. All tags with a given name (of the class that code is being generated for): `%classTag:"annotations"%`

But unfortunately, I cannot combine these macros, i.e., I cannot pass one interface to the `classTag` macro so that I can retrieve the tags of that particular interface (and not the one I'm generating code for). Is there a way to  get classTags of a specific class / interface?
I also tried to create a separate code generation template and "call" it from the main class code generation template. But inside my template, the `classTag` macro still only gets the tags of the class.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone here is using EA's code generation. I don't and Geert probably neither. So maybe you should ask this on Sparx' forum (with a link to this question).

Comment: I had to modify an existing template a couple of years ago, but if at all possible I try to stay as far away as possible from them. There are a few Sparx employees that seem to know this topic very well, but they usually only frequent the Sparx user forum.

Comment: @qwerty_so, Geert Bellekens: Thank you both, I will try my luck on EA's forum. 
And this is only for a proof of concept. So as soon as I know that this is in general possible, I will "stay as far away as possible" ^^. Fiddling around with the templates so far wasn't really what I would call fun or rewarding.

Comment: Yep, same story here. Generally I found code generation not _that_ helpful as I formerly thought. I used the API to create code which worked well. But now I know that code should be kept in code and design in UML. The only helpful bridge (for me) is when you RE some existing code. Good luck in any case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above and especially because of an answer to my question in EA's forum, I was able to setup a little proof of concept achieving what I wanted. I'm answering my question to document my solution in case someone has a similar problem in the future.

After Eve's hint in EA's forum I looked into creating an AddIn for Enterprise Architect to use this AddIn from a code generation template. I started by writing a basic AddIn as explained by @Geert Bellekens in [this tutorial](https://bellekens.com/2011/01/29/tutorial-create-your-first-c-enterprise-architect-add-in-in-10-minutes/). Afterwards I changed the AddIn to fit my needs. This is how I finally got the tagged values (annotations) of the interfaces a class realizes:

**First step:**
Inside a code generation template, I get all the interfaces a class realizes and pass them to my AddIn:

```
$interfaces=%list="ClassInterface" @separator=", "%
%EXEC_ADD_IN("MyAddin","getInterfaceTags", $interfaces)%
```

**Second step:**
As documented [here](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/functionmacros.html) the repository objects gets passed along with the EXEC_ADD_IN call. I use the repository object and query for all interfaces using the names contained in $interfaces. I can then get the tagged values of each interface element. Simple prototype that achieves this for a single interface:

```
public Object getInterfaceTags(EA.Repository repo, Object args)
{
  String[] interfaceNames = args as String[];
  String firstInterfaceName = interfaceNames[0];
  EA.Element interfaceElement = repo.GetElementsByQuery("Simple", firstInterfaceName).GetAt(0);
  String tag = interfaceElement.TaggedValues.GetAt(0);
  return interfaceElement.Name + " has tag value" + tag.Value;
}
```

I know, there are a couple of shortcomings but this is just a simple proof of concept for an idea that will most likely never be production code.